# Writing Custom State Manager for JSF2

Tags: jsf-2

I have performance issue (OOM error) with my application written using JSF2.0. I could see the heap size growing tremendously for more than 25 users and finally ends up in OOM. As part of performance tuning planning to have the VIEW STATE saved in a cache server.

Any pointers to do the same would be very helpful. As a starting point, I have overridden SaveView(..) method to store the UIViewRoot in cache and restore it just by using the viewId. It gets called, but the problem is, a consistent ArrayIndexOut... exception from ServerStateHelper (which I believe is the default Server side saving method helper) is called and it throws this exception.

Anyone tried custom StateManager implementation with success? Please share.

Comment: JSF implementation/version are you using? Have you positively identified viewstate management to be the root cause of your performace issue?